# Handlebars variable inside each loop (Accessing object key value)

Tags: handlebars.js

One of my components needs to fetch different data from a property based on a parameter I pass it. The parameterHolder is an Object with keys and parameter is the key name.

```
{{component-name parameterHolderBinding=parameterHolder parameterValueBinding=parameter}}
```

I'm trying to loop through it like so

```
{{#each item in parameterHolder.[{{parameter}}]}}

{{/#each}}
```

But it's not working. When I try,

```
{{parameterHolder.keyName}}
```

I'm getting [Object] which is correct. Could someone please point out the right way do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working by dynamically creating new properties.

In my controller -

```
parameterUpdatedObserver: function () 
{
    var reference = this;
    $.each(parameterHolder, function (key, value) {
        reference.set('parameterHolderName'+key, value);
    });
}.observes('parameterHolder')
```

And my component - 
{{component-name parameterHolderBinding=parameterHolderNameKey parameterValueBinding=parameter}}

I can probably abstract it up one more level using another component. If anyone has a better solution, please do post it.